# One payment gateway(paypal) but business accounts across different account providers

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

I am working on a website which involves users paying to each other. The payment gateway is going to be paypal., now does it require every user to have their business account with paypal? (or) is it possible to let them have their business account with any business account provider?.

Would appreciate any pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define what you mean by 'business account'. If you mean a merchant account at an acquiring bank: no, that's not required. If you mean a PayPal Business account; no, that's not require either, recipients can have a Premier account as well.
Technically, you'll want to look into Adaptive Chained Payments -- this allows you to chain the payment along multiple recipients (up to 9, if I recall correctly).

Have a look at [Introducing Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/docs/DOC-1408)
Or [dev guides](https://www.x.com/community/ppx/documentation#ap)